# how to search a japanese pdf file with ios

Tags: iphone

I can search english pdf files by scanning the 'Tj' and 'TJ' flags.
like this: http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42

But i can not search japanese pdf file.
The result of scanning is like these:

> C   ¥ ¢ *   £  y y         y   y
>   y w ù › C   ¥ ¢ *   £ y     y  y ¹ Ñ Ä
>   ¢ £ ž › C t x | Â © µ Ä ¤ Ã   » | ¯ ï
>   Í € å “ ž · ï Ò å s r w t €

I have tried

```
NSString *destString = [data stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingUnicode];
```

and

```
NSString* destString = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(string) encoding:kCFStringEncodingUnicode];
```

but it didnt work.
How to get correct encoding string?

Comment: Could it be that the Japanese PDF file is compressed but the English PDF file wasn't? You can use a tool like `pdftk` to uncompress a pdf file and see if that makes a difference.